# syntax error, unexpected '[' on [0]

Tags: php

I get an error on this line:

```
$name = $html->find('a.ProfileHeaderCard-nameLink')[0]->plaintext;
```

The error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['
```

How can I make this work? It works perfectly on localhost for some reason.

Comment: Are there different PHP versions on localhost and live server?

Comment: What output do you get from doing something like var_export($html->find('a.ProfileHeaderCard-nameLink')); on each server?

Comment: $name = $html->find('a.ProfileHeaderCard-nameLink'); $name = $name[0]->plaintext;`

Comment: try breaking the statements into two instead of chaining.

Comment: Your PHP version is way out of date. That parser feature was addaed in PHP 5.4. As of http://php.net/supported-versions.php , PHP 5.4 is end-of-life since fall 2015

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,

```html
$name = $html->find('a.ProfileHeaderCard-nameLink');
$name = $name[0]->plaintext;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are running the same PHP versions locally and on your server? Accessing an array directly after returning it from a functin is a feature added in PHP 5.4, see http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php